# How to use the "TSC.CSVRequestOptions()" class from Tableau Python API to filter the result when extracting a view to csv?

Tags: python, filter, extract, tableau-api, export-to-csv

I'm trying to extract a view in css from Tableau using the python API and I'd like to filter the result by taking only some moths into account.

I first import the packages:

```
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils import querying
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import openpyxl
```

I'm connecting to the Tableau server:

```
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(<my_token_name>, <my_token>)
server = TSC.Server('https://<tableau_server_name>', use_server_version=True)
server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)
```

I retrieve the needed workbook:

```
for wb in TSC.Pager(server.workbooks):
    if wb.name == '<my_workbook_name>':
        good_wb_id = wb.id
        
good_wb = server.workbooks.get_by_id(good_wb_id)
```

I then create my request option. Actually in the view I have a list of months and I'd like to keep only some of them (it's normal that the month name is in Spanish):

```
csv_req_option = TSC.CSVRequestOptions()
csv_req_option.vf("Month of Invoice Date", 'enero')
```

And I finally retrieve the needed views in the workbook and I create dataframes from them to be able to process them:

```
views_to_keep = ['Platinium','Titanium', 'Gold', 'SENA']

desired_views = [view for view in good_wb.views if view.name.split()[0] in views_to_keep]

dfs = {}

for view in desired_views:
    server.views.populate_csv(view, req_options=csv_req_option)
    with open('../csv_tableau/%s.csv'%view.name, 'wb') as f:
        # Perform byte join on the CSV data
        f.write(b''.join(view.csv))
        f.close()
        
    df = pd.read_csv('../csv_tableau/%s.csv'%view.name)
    dfs[view.name] = df
    os.remove('../csv_tableau/%s.csv'%view.name)
```

But when I check the data, the filter was not applied. The extract toke all the months into account.

I've tried to follow this tutorial https://medium.com/snake-charmer-python-and-analytics/query-your-tableau-view-data-like-a-boss-using-python-and-pandas-68483abac86 but I have to use a token to log into Tableau so I have to use these libraries:

```
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils import querying
import tableauserverclient as TSC
```

Comment: I can't say this is your only error but filters are passed in the url, therefore if you have spaces, "Month of Invoice Date" you have to account for that like medium link describes.  Spaces need to be encoded with "%20".

Comment: That's unfortunately not the problem. It worked for another filter with space in the name: `csv_req_option = TSC.CSVRequestOptions()`
`csv_req_option.vf("Product Brand", 'Brand')`